# Defining the place depending on the user django-channels

Tags: html, django, chat, django-channels

I'am making a chat app using django-channels. In my front-end chat I want one user on one side and the other user on the other side, I try something like this:

```
   {% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}
    {% if chat.user == user.username %}

        <div class="msg right-msg" id="side">
          <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg)"></div>

          <div class="msg-bubble">
              <div class="msg-info">
              <div class="msg-info-name" id="user">{{ chat.user }}</div>
              <div class="msg-info-time"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="msg-text" id="buttom">{{ chat.message }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
    {% elif chat.user != user.username %}

        <div class="msg left-msg" id="side">
          <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg)"></div>

          <div class="msg-bubble">
              <div class="msg-info">
              <div class="msg-info-name" id="user">{{ chat.user }}</div>
              <div class="msg-info-time"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="msg-text" id="buttom">{{ chat.message }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

the class msg right-msg tells the right place and the class msg left-msg tells the other place,
it seems it works, but not as I expected. At the end it looks like this:
[chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MomIq.jpg)

does anybody know want can I do to classified the side depending on the user?

Comment: You're comparing chat.user to user.username. Isn't chat.user a user object? if yes then it's wrong to compare it with username which is string in which case you will always get the second case

Comment: @Kenscholars, So what I need to do is to change the chat.user?, and how can I compare if that is not my user? and defined the place depending on the user?

Comment: if `chat.user` really is a User object then you should compare `chat.user.username` to `user.username`. I can't see your models so I am not sure but you can't compare different data types like user and username. Instead compare username with username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an if statement with django template tag:

```
{% if user.username != chat.user %}"msg left-msg"{% elif user.username == chat.user %}"msg right-msg"{% endif %}
```

Comment: So the if inside the loop?

Comment: yes, inside the loop, if not, the can call depending on your model, like object.first or object.second